# Secure joomla admin: Disable editing css/html files for templates

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates, administrator

I'd like to disable entering and editing any files in the Templates/Templates area. We have some security issues with template files (they are edited by hackers) and we are afraid that it is used for hacking.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the permissions on the template files and directories using the hosting administration panel(eg. cPanel, VirtualMin,Plesk,etc.) via their respective file manager tool. You would probably need to change the first value to a 6 from a 7 limit write access but depending on the requirements of the file or folder that may cause other issues on your site with updates etc.

However that is only addressing the symptoms, files being changed, and not the cause of your problem, how are hackers able to get into your site to make the changes.

If a Hacker(s) is able to change a file or two then they can probably change the permissions as suggested above and still make their changes.

You need to find how they are able to access your website or hosting environment, remove them and put in place measures to prevent them access it again.